# How do you restart foreman upon each request for a simple Django Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

My current app is running in my local environment and has the following in its Procfile: web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -

I'm looking for a way to change this so that foreman restarts itself upon each web request so I don't have to do so every time I make a code change.

Comment: So just to be clear, this is a problem you're facing in your local environment and **not** on Heroku, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question but I've just realised [I asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189188/how-to-restart-foreman-when-code-in-a-django-site-changes) yesterday.

The solution is to add the [`--reload`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload) option to gunicorn. So your Procfile will look like:

```
web: gunicorn --reload hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```