# How to restart Foreman when code in a Django site changes?

Tags: django, gunicorn, foreman

I'm running a Django website in a Vagrant box that (roughly) mirrors a Heroku set-up. It uses Foreman with a Procfile like this:

```
web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi > /vagrant/gunicorn.log 2>&1
```

However, when I change my Django code, the server doesn't restart or reload the code, which makes development... painful!

How can I make Foreman serve the new code when it changes?

Comment: It's not foreman you need to restart, but gunicorn - and that has the [`--reload`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload) option that will do it for you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, since you mention development, do you not use `runserver`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ugh, you're right, of course! And I just spent an hour trying to get [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) to work :) If you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Sayse I often do, but in this case I'm trying to mirror my Heroku environment as closely as is feasible, so I want to use gunicorn and run it with foreman. This might be more trouble than it's worth :)